# What is the Raspberry Pi?

Tags: hardware

Can anyone explain to me the Raspberry Pi? I am having trouble understanding what it is.

Comment: While I did answer this question, you could easily research this topic yourself.  Therefore, I did vote to put this question on hold.

Comment: you should definitely figure out first what is "Raspberry" and what is "Pi". i'd recommend wildlife.stackexchange.com and math.stackexchange.com for that purpose.

Answer (score 9):

Take a look at the [Raspberry Pi FAQs](http://www.raspberrypi.org/faqs):

> ### What’s a Raspberry Pi?
>
> The Raspberry Pi is a credit-card sized computer that plugs into your
>   TV and a keyboard. It’s a capable little PC which can be used for many
>   of the things that your desktop PC does, like spreadsheets,
>   word-processing and games. It also plays high-definition video. We
>   want to see it being used by kids all over the world to learn
>   programming.

Answer (score 2):

The RPi is a computer learning and exploration kit aimed at kids, but very popular with techies too. It is a bare board ARM based computer that is a little bigger than most smart phones, plugs into a Micro USB Phone charger for power and a TV (analog RCA or HDMI) as a monitor. It has GPIO pins to experiment with computer/realworld interactions (such as lighting LEDs for status indicators, driving motors, monitoring button presses on custom buttons....

It is designed to be the brains to a modern electronics experiment kit, and as a cheap platform for teaching computer programming.